# Checking declared member function in MSVC2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, sfinae, c++03

I've wrote the following code and it compiles and works as expected under GCC 4.7 and under MSVC 2013 but fails to compile under MSVC 2012:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename TClass>
struct IsLoadableHelper {
    template<typename T, T t> struct Helper {};

    struct Mixin1 {
        void Load(std::istream*);
    };
    struct MixedStruct1 : public Mixin1, public TClass {};
    // template<typename U>
    // static char f(Helper<void(TClass::*)(std::istream*), &TClass::Load>*);
    template<typename U>
    static long f(Helper<void(Mixin1::*)(std::istream*), &U::Load>*);
    template<typename U>
    static char f(...);

    enum { value = sizeof(f<MixedStruct1>(0)) == sizeof(char) };
};

struct Loadable
{
    void Load(std::istream*);
};


struct DerivedLoadable : Loadable
{};


struct NotLoadable
{
};


int main(void)
{
    std::cout << IsLoadableHelper<NotLoadable>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << IsLoadableHelper<Loadable>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << IsLoadableHelper<DerivedLoadable>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

template<typename TClass>
struct IsLoadableHelper {
    template<typename T, T t> struct Helper {};

    struct Mixin1 {
        void Load(std::istream*);
    };
    struct MixedStruct1 : public Mixin1, public TClass {};
    template<typename U>
    static long f(Helper<void(Mixin1::*)(std::istream*), &U::Load>*);
    template<typename U>
    static char f(...);

    enum { value = sizeof(f<MixedStruct1>(0)) == sizeof(char) };
};

struct Loadable
{
    void Load(std::istream*);
};


struct NotLoadable
{
};

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << IsLoadableHelper<NotLoadable>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << IsLoadableHelper<Loadable>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

During compilation under MSVC 2012 it returns the following error:

```
1>Source.cpp(22): error C3867: 'IsLoadableHelper<TClass>::Mixin1::Load': function call missing  argument list; use '&IsLoadableHelper<TClass>::Mixin1::Load' to create a pointer to member
1>          with
1>          [
1>              TClass=Loadable
1>          ]
1>          Source.cpp(43) : see reference to class template instantiation 'IsLoadableHelper<TClass>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              TClass=Loadable
1>          ]
1>Source.cpp(22): error C3867: 'IsLoadableHelper<TClass>::Mixin1::Load': function call missing argument list; use '&IsLoadableHelper<TClass>::Mixin1::Load' to create a pointer to member
1>          with
1>          [
1>              TClass=DerivedLoadable
1>          ]
1>          Source.cpp(44) : see reference to class template instantiation  'IsLoadableHelper<TClass>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              TClass=DerivedLoadable
1>          ]
```

I see that it fails to resolve pointer to Load function and advises me to get pointer to base class. This is expected. But it reports an error instead of following SFINAE and just continuing and THIS is unexpected. I am restricted to use C++03 only and I need to make this piece of code work under Visual Studio 2012 Update 4. How it may be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

How about a bit simpler alternative:

```
template<typename TClass>
struct IsLoadableHelper {
    template<typename T, T> struct Helper;

    template<typename U>
    static long f(Helper<void (U::*)(std::istream*), &U::Load>*);
    template<typename U>
    static char f(...);

    enum { value = sizeof(f<TClass>(0)) == sizeof(char) };
};
```

Would this satisfy MSVC2012? MSVC2013 is happy!

Comment: Looks like it would not work in the case if there is Base::Load(istream*) and no Derived::Load(istream*).